# plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'classes' using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

i am new to python and deep learning, i trained a multi classifier model and want to plot a confusion matrix but i am facing an error
here is my code

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
category_names = sorted(os.listdir('D:/DiabaticRetinopathy/mq_dataset/DR_Normal/train'))
print(category_names)
cm = confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes = category_names, title='Confusion Matrix', normalize=False, figname = 'Confusion_matrix_concrete.jpg')
```

i upddated my sklearn to 0.24 version. i restarted my kernel after updating but still its giving an error:

```
TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'classes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `labels` instead of classes, then Remove `title, figname`

```
plot_confusion_matrix(X = test_generator.classes, y_true = y_pred,labels= category_names, normalize=False)
```

Documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

Comment: thanks but now it giving an error  "plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title' " what keyword should i use for title and figure

Comment: Yes.. based on the documentation, title and figname is not there in the syntax.. kindly remove title and figname

Comment: yes i removed both title and figure but it  now showing an error :  plot_confusion_matrix() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'y_true' while my code look like   `cm = confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, labels = category_names)`

Comment: test_generator.classes, y_pred

Comment: i changed code to `plot_confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred, labels = category_names, normalize=False)` but it still gives error "TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'
"

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyword **labels**, but not classes, so you can change it to that.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the keyword classes you provided is not a keyword that this function recognizes. This happens in your last line.

The documentation gives a list of the keywords that you can use:
[doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html)